# Transfer data from Oracl to MySQL -- script

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have two databases. The first one is a Oracle Database and contains a table that I want to transfer to a MySQL Database. The databases are not on the same server.

Which programming language should I use ?
Is there an other method instead of writing a programm ? 
And how can I do it ?
In addition this transfer should happen in a regular frequency. For example every hour.
(I can tell the Task Manager to run a programm at a specific time so that would be no problem if I would have a program.)

I already tried Python, but as I have to install every single module for MySQL and Oracle and the Oracle module is not working I decided to give up on this.
It should be simple and quick.

Comment: Why do you need it? Describe a typical scenario, please. It helps us to offer you the best solutions

Comment: The Oracle DB contains a row of number for example L KL8912 L KI8665 ... . This row of data should now be transfered to the MySQL DB. This DB contains a Table named "plalis" with "ID","Names" and "Plas". I want to insert these data from Oracle (e.g. L KL8912) into the "Plas" column in MySQL.

Comment: Do you want to do it in two steps (extract data from the Oracle Database and then load it into mysql manually) or you want to press the button and complete all this task?